# Python Use Socket as Global Variable

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, global, attributeerror

I have created a function that establishes the TCP/IP socket connection to the server. Now I would like to reuse the socket for other tasks in my application. So that I have:

```
import socket

def creat_tcp_connection():
    sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock_tcp.connect(("163.173.96.12", 32000))
    return sock_tcp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    creat_tcp_connection()
    texte = "PING\n"
    creat_tcp_connection.sock_tcp.send(texte.encode('utf-8'))
    data=creat_tcp_connection.sock_tcp.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print("Received ", str(data))
```

But "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sock_tcp'". How can use the socket
sock_tcp inside the creat_tcp_connection() function

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access attributes of the function, not the return value of the function. Try this:

```
import socket

def creat_tcp_connection():
    sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock_tcp.connect(("163.173.96.12", 32000))
    return sock_tcp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = creat_tcp_connection()
    texte = "PING\n"
    sock.send(texte.encode('utf-8'))
    data=sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print("Received ", str(data))
```

Comment: If I do like this sock = creat_tcp_connection() will return an object and i can not send by using sock_tcp. 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: ```sock``` would be a variable (not a function) containing a socket object which has a [send function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send). This code works for me, it seems to me that you are mistakenly trying to access the attributes of ```create_tcp_connection``` instead of the object returned by that function.

Comment: Thank you, Stanley! This code worked for me. I have another question, how can you use socket in other functions. For instance: I have a function 

def disconnect():
    sock_tcp.close()

but sock_tcp is not a global variable. Can I use Class? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You should pass the socket as a parameter to the disconnect function, so the function signature looks something like: disconnect(socket) and you call it by passing the socket to it. You could also use a socket class to manage the socket but this comment is too small to fully explain that so see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)